# Как правильно сделать обновляемый вывод в консоли?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как нужно сделать вывод в консоль так, чтобы она обновлялась правильно?

У меня есть код:

```
print(f'Warming up threads... [' + str(len(ips) - i) + ']', end="\r")
```

Вывод в консоли выглядит так:

> Warming up threads... [1200]

Но если будет выведена строка, которая на 1 символ короче предыдущей, то выглядеть это будет так:

> Warming up threads... [999]]

Соответственно, если останется запустить только 1 тред, то строка обретёт следующий вид:

> Warming up threads... [1]]]]

Comment: `print(f'Warming up threads... [' + str(len(ips) - i) + ']', end="\r")` серьезно? :) вы используете форматированную строку, а формируете ее через `+`. Так будет лучше: `print(f'Warming up threads... [{len(ips) - i}]', end="\r")`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5291044 - может быть полезно

Answer (score 1):

При написании в новой строке консоли каретка уже в начале строки, после написания она будет стоять за последним символом.
Поэтому, добавляя `\r` мы возвращаем каретку в начало строки и все последующие символы заменяют те, что были в тех же позиция. Чтобы не было артефактов, очищаем строку сдвигая каретку, заполняя пробелами и снова сдвигая каретку
Пример артефакта:

- Если вывести сначала строку большей длины, а после меньшей:
- `Current value [10254]`
- `Current value [999]4]`

Пример:

```
import time
import sys

for ips in (10254, 1, 10, 1, 10254, 999):
    sys.stdout.write('\r' + ' ' * 50 + '\r')  # Очищение строки
    sys.stdout.write(f'Current value [{ips}]')
    sys.stdout.flush()

    time.sleep(0.5)
```

---

**P.S.**

В старой версии `PyCharm` мною был замечен баг, из-за которого не работал перевод каретки `\r`. Поэтому, лучше проверять и на терминалах в ОС (например `cmd` в `windows`)

Comment: Ну тогда получается тот же самый результат, что и в случае с обыкновенным `print()`. Я хочу, чтобы обновлялась уже выведенная строка, а не добавлялись новые.

Answer (score -1):

Можно через `os.system('cls')`. Выйдет

```
import time
import os

x = 1200

while x:
    os.system('cls')
    print('Warming up threads... [' + str(x) + ']')`
```